# Count elements in vector or check whether element is in array in D

Tags: arrays, d

How can I check whether an element is in an array or count occurences of a specific element?

I know that I can hack that myself:

```
int main()
{
  int [] a = [1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,6,3,3,3];
  assert(count(a,6) == 2);
  assert(contains(a,7) == false);
  return 0;
}

uint count(T)(T[] a, T t){
  uint cnt = 0;
  foreach(elem; a){
    if(elem == t) ++cnt;
  }
  return cnt;
}

bool contains(T)(T[] a, T t){
  foreach(elem; a){
    if(elem == t) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

but there must be a "library-way" to do it!

**edit:** I just compared std.algorithm's `canFind()` and my `contains()` and it turns out, that `contains` is faster. Strange but true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *count* see: [`std.algorithm.count`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#count).

For *contains*: [`std.algorithm.canFind`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#canFind). For sorted arrays you can use [`SortedRange`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#.SortedRange) (`contains` method uses binary search).